# Bootstrap datepicker, make default view today's date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I'm displaying dates on a bootstrap datepicker calendar like so;

```
$(".datepicker").data("datepicker").setDates($('#mydates').data('dates'));
```

However this has the unwanted side effect of making the default view the last date displayed. I want the calendar to default to displaying the current month but I don't see how to do this in the docs.

If I add `"setDate": new Date()` to the datepicker it clears my previously loaded dates.

So how can I load dates and set the default view to todays date?

Comment: Is this for the Eternicode datepicker? If so, when you initialize it, it has a `startDate` parameter.

Comment: @Karl No, bootstrap datepicker